# Terraform validation on list object using optional variable

Tags: terraform

Think I am pretty close to getting this but...

The validation here works when I have the accelerator_type set in both list objects but I want to be able to use the validation on individual objects not all objects, if you remove accelerator_type ​from one of the objects in the list in the .tfvars it will fail validation.

```
variable "notebook_configurations" {
  type = list(object({
    notebook_name       = string
    accelerator_type    = optional(string, "")
  }))
  default = [{
    "notebook_name"       = "my-first-notebook"
  }]
  validation {
    condition = length([
      for o in var.notebook_configurations : true
      if contains(["ACCELERATOR_TYPE_UNSPECIFIED", "NVIDIA_TESLA_K80"], o.accelerator_type)
    ]) == length(var.notebook_configurations)
    error_message = "Possible types of this accelerator. - ('ACCELERATOR_TYPE_UNSPECIFIED', 'NVIDIA_TESLA_K80')"
  }
#  validation {
#    condition = alltrue([
#      for obj in var.notebook_configurations : contains(["ACCELERATOR_TYPE_UNSPECIFIED", "NVIDIA_TESLA_K80"], obj.accelerator_type)
#    ])
#    error_message = "Possible types of this accelerator. - ('ACCELERATOR_TYPE_UNSPECIFIED', 'NVIDIA_TESLA_K80')."
#  }
}
```

terraform.tfvars

```
notebook_configurations = [{
  notebook_name       = "test1-standard-notebook",
  accelerator_type =  "ACCELERATOR_TYPE_UNSPECIFIED"
  },
  {
    notebook_name       = "test2-standard-notebook",
    accelerator_type =  "NVIDIA_TESLA_K80"
  }
]
```

error:
│

> Error: Invalid value for variable │  │   on validate_variable.tf line
> 2: │    2: variable "notebook_configurations" { │
> ├──────────────── │     │ var.notebook_configurations is list of
> object with 2 elements │  │ Possible types of this accelerator. -
> ('ACCELERATOR_TYPE_UNSPECIFIED', 'NVIDIA_TESLA_K80') │  │ This was
> checked by the validation rule at validate_variable.tf:11,3-13.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add an OR operator to the conditional to allow the default value set in the variable definition to pass, e.g.:

```
  validation {
    condition = length([
      for o in var.notebook_configurations : true
      if contains(["ACCELERATOR_TYPE_UNSPECIFIED", "NVIDIA_TESLA_K80"], o.accelerator_type) || o.accelerator_type == ""
    ]) == length(var.notebook_configurations)
    error_message = "Possible types of this accelerator. - ('ACCELERATOR_TYPE_UNSPECIFIED', 'NVIDIA_TESLA_K80')"
  }
```

In this case, the condition checks if the `accelerator_type` is set to `""`, which it's the default value set in here:

```
  type = list(object({
    notebook_name    = string
    accelerator_type = optional(string, "")
  }))
```

Comment: Okay, this works for now, although I am going to just at the empty quotes to the main list instead of an or statement. Cheers